# Is there a universal way to "close" a <select> dropdown menu (not .blur() )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

There's a neat trick you can use to ["close"](http://jsfiddle.net/vqA3M/6/) a `<select>` dropdown menu.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('#test').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#test').show();
    },20);
});​
```

This seems to always work for Chrome and Firefox on Windows. IE works in my actual code, but when I test the jsfiddle code in IE, it doesn't work. And on a mac, this doesn't work for any browser. The difference between Mac and Windows is that on Mac, the options are opened in their own element (kinda - inspecting the page shows no new elements). So the dropdown bar hides and comes back, but the new menu with the options aren't considered a part of `$('#test')` so they don't hide. In Windows, the menu with options is considered part of `$('#test')` so when you hide that, the menu hides along with it.

**So the question is, is there a way to "close" a `<select>` dropdown menu that works in any browser and on any OS?**

---

**UPDATE**

I don't mean using `.blur()` and this is why. I have some code that emulates a dropdown menu but is actually `<select multiple>`. So I have just a normal `<select>` visible and when I click on it, I replace it with an absolutely positioned `<select multiple>` element. After selecting the options, this goes away and the `<select>` element comes back. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: How about `$('#test').click(function(){ $(this).blur(); });` -> http://jsfiddle.net/vqA3M/7/

Comment: Try: `var t = this, p = t.parentNode, n = t.nextSibling;` then in the callback: `p.insertBefore(t, n);`

Comment: Just so you know, Webkits browsers have a problem with select and the click event. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-click-on-select-boxes-webkit I'm pretty sure it can happen to other browser too.

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UNzTg/ I added a `.removeChild()` before the `setTimeout` in case it offers any better outcome.

Comment: Instead of on `click`, why don't you use on `focus`?

Comment: @user1689607 Instead of using basic Javascript, you may want to use things like jQuery `remove` and `append`. Just remember, any items you remove from the DOM won't have events re-bound to them, so I'm not sure removing them is the best approach.

Comment: @ianpgall: Items removed in this manner will not lose any handlers or data. If we use jQuery, then we would need to use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()` in order to keep handlers and such bound. The reason I didn't use jQuery here, is that the `insertBefore` will behave just like `appendChild` if `nextSibling` returned `null`. I think with jQuery, we would need to explicitly test to see if `this` has a `.next()` sibling, and then reinsert the element using either `.append()` or `.insertBefore()` depending on the outcome.

Comment: ...here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UNzTg/1/ But even that really isn't safe, because the next sibling could be a text node, which jQuery will ignore. So if you have the `select` then a `textNode` then another element, the `select` will be reinserted after the `textNode` instead of before where it originally was. http://jsfiddle.net/UNzTg/2/

Comment: @ianpgall - Changing my code to `focus` instead of `click` worked. It at least worked in Chrome, FF, and IE in Windows, and Chrome and Safari on a Mac. Go ahead and post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Aust Sounds good! Just made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the event from `click` to `focus`, it might help:

```
$("#test").focus(function () {
    // Your original code

    // or: this.blur();
    // just DON'T call this.focus()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it yet but I would imagine, you can just

```
$('select').blur();
```

or set focus on something else to close it

Update - oh there you go first commenter has the fiddle

Comment: well if you are going for UI then you can make a dropdown without even using select and use js to populate the form element when submitting. I think scion.ca has something like that in their forms

Answer (score 1):

`select` is not meant for this, you can however create some other markup to `fake` the `select` layout.

HTML

option 1

option 2

option 3

​

JS

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
}).find('li').not(':first').on('hover',function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});​
```

CSS

```
ul {
   list-style:none  ;
   border : solid 1px Gray;    
   width: 80px;
   height: 20px;
   overflow:hidden;
   cursor:pointer;
}
ul.open {
 height: 60px;   
}
```

​

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yy797/). You can style the markup as you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.blur()` on `click()`.. unfortunately I cannot test them all now..

```
$('select').click(function(){ 
   $(this).blur(); 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vqA3M/7/

Comment: I don't mean to close the dropdown menu after choosing an item. I mean closing it immediately so a user couldn't select an item.

Comment: @Aust Why the hell would you want to do that?

Comment: If that's the goal, why not just add a "disabled" attribute to the select tag?  Why give the user the weird experience of the menu popping open and closed?

Comment: @Phrogz, @redlena - Haha well what I'm doing is when the user opens the dropdown, it hides that dropdown and shows a `<select multiple>` list with the same options instead that is absolutely positioned. It's for the UI. Drop-downs are much prettier than `<select multiple>`

Comment: @Aust It seems like `<select>` showing the drop down options works differently in webkit browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/vqA3M/11/ -> Shows the drop down option even after the focus is in next element.